# Referencing different row in different column with same date

Tags: sql, case

Please find sample date below. I want to create a new column Payment_received, that finds payment_dates which are not NULL, and subtracts (payment date - earliest SMS date for that account number). For example, for account number 12345, the calculation would be (2021-07-22 - 2021-07-20) = 2 days and for account number 99999, the calculation would be (2021-08-13 - 2021-08-10) = 3 days. I was thinking if I could create a case when to do this calculation, however, I don't know how to reference different rows for the same account number.

```
 SMS_Date     Account Number  Payment_Date     Payment_received      
 2021-07-20        12345         NULL               NULL
 2021-07-21        12345         NULL               NULL
 2021-07-22        12345        2021-07-22            2
 2021-08-10        99999         NULL               NULL
 2021-08-11        99999         NULL               NULL
 2021-08-12        99999         NULL               NULL
 2021-08-13        99999       2021-08-13            3
```

Comment: Lots of ways.  But you need to tag your question with the database you're using, show your tables (names) / structure (column names/types), some sample data and the output you expect, given that data.

Comment: What if you have another payment for account 12345 one month later?  Do you want the days calculated to be from the start of the account history (2021-07-20 to 2021-09-15, as an example)?

Answer (score 0):

Use `CROSS APPLY` to find earliest SMS date for each row in original table.

```
SELECT
    pi.*,
    CASE
        WHEN pi.Payment_Date IS NOT NULL THEN DATEDIFF(d, smsdate.First_SMS_Date, pi.Payment_Date)
        ELSE NULL
    END AS Payment_Received
FROM
    PaymentsInfo pi
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            MIN(SMS_Date) AS First_SMS_Date
        FROM
            PaymentsInfo smst
        WHERE
            pi.Payment_Date IS NOT NULL AND pi.Account_Number = smst.Account_Number
    ) smsdate
```